# array.push.apply to implment 'concat' with explain

Tags: javascript

Learning reactive programming and encouter this bit of code,

```
results.push.apply(results, subArray);
```

understand apply

**FULL CODE**

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

but when this code appear and get my head spinning. it's pretty much doing the `concat`. can someone please explain?

many thanks

Comment: what is the problem? you are getting the unexpected result or some errors ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***some_function***.**apply**(**obj**, [**a**, **b**, **c**])

is (basically...) the same as:

***obj***.**some_function**(**a**, **b**, **c**)

Which is: *"invoke the function, referenced by 'some_function', with 'obj' as the 'this argument', and the list of parameters as parameters"*.

That is, calling the function (in your case, 'push') as if it was a member of 'obj' (in you case 'results').

See: [Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for details.

An example to play around with:

```
var o1 = {
    name: 'First object',
    f: function(a, b ,c) {
           console.log(this, a, b, c);
       }
};
o1.f('Hello', 'World', '!');
var o2 = {
    name: 'Second object'
};
var some_function = o1.f; // This illustrates that the function is not bound to o1...
some_function.apply(o2, ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']);
```

Comment: ty mate :) nicely explained

Comment: Thanks :) I hope it clicked!

Answer (score 4):

Lets me explain you.

As per the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) first parameter for `apply` API is `this` argument and the second parameter is an array of argument that is applied by `apply` to the calling method.

**Whats author intention by this code?**

Well i guess author is tired of pushing each and every value from its index. For example:

```
var arr = [];
var val = [1,2,3,4];
arr.push(val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]);
```

So the author chose to use the API that does this same job for him which is shorter and concise. Read [Array.prototype.push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) documentation, It can accept *n* arguments. So,

```
arr.push.apply(arr, val);
```

**Explaining the second part of the code in the question:**

I guess the author of the code intention is to concatenate the multidimensional array. For example follow the code below:

```
Array.prototype.concatAll = function() {
    var results = [];
    this.forEach(function(subArray) {
        results.push.apply(results, subArray);
    });

    return results;
};

var arr = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]];
console.log(arr.concatAll()); // Prints [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: guess i wasn't properly understand apply(), good explaination

Comment: yep definitely got it